# How to automatically set a default route on RPI when ppp0 (3G) connection is established?

Tags: raspbian, 3g

I want to connect a RPI to the internet via an UMTS stick. I could get it working with some manual interaction. As the RPI is place on an external location where i don't have access to all the time, it should completely "come up" automatically when its booted.

**What is did:**

`sudo apt-get install wvdial ppp sg3-utils`

set `/etc/wvdial.conf` to:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ

; Huawei E182E:
;Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0

; Huawei E173
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2

Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","web.vodafone.de"
;Modem Type = Analog Modem
Modem Type = USB Modem
ISDN = 0
New PPPD = yes
Username = ''
Password = ''
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
;Modem = /dev/bus/usb/001/011
Dial Command = ATD
Stupid Mode = 1
Phone = *99#
Baud = 115200
Auto Reconnect = on
```

set `/etc/ppp/peers/wvdial` to (no idea if this is required and what this does?):

```
noauth
local
name wvdial
usepeerdns
```

created `/etc/network/interfaces.d/ppp0` (i have the impression that this does nothing as it does not "up" the interface at boot and the route is not set)

```
auto ppp0
iface ppp0 inet wvdial
up ip route add default dev ppp0
```

as the above interface configuration does not activate the interface at boot, i added this to `/etc/rc.local`-> `wvdial&`

**When i (re-)boot the RPI after all these settings, the interface is properly activated but my traffic is not routed to the UMTS interface.**
When i execute `ip route add default dev ppp0`, everything works like it should be and the UTMS interface (ppp0) is used for internet traffic.

How can i automatically add this default route when the device is booted? or maybe better, when the ppp0 interface is connected?

Answer (score 0):

I found that i needed to add some extra parameters to the ppp connection file. The lines bellow where missing in `/etc/ppp/peers/wvdial`

```
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
```

A complete list of valid parameters can be found here under `Options`: https://ppp.samba.org/pppd.html